# Tag Creation with low-none reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I wrote a [question about djing](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11677/djing-where-to-begin) and wanted to add some tags to it like "djing", "tutorial" but couldn't because of the 150+ rep.

If there are "too few" tags in the system it could be allowed to "create" some even with lower reputation.

Answer (score 4):

The rep requirements are Stack Exchange-wide. They are there for a very good reason - in this case to stop people proposing new tags until they have spent time interacting on a particular site.

Until you have enough rep you can ask (through commenting) for a mod or higher rep member to add tags for you.

[tutorial](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorial) is not a good idea for a tag. This entire site is about questions and answers, pointing someone to a tutorial is not necessarily useful as the tutorial may move, it may be outdated etc. Additionally, asking for a 'good' tutorial is pretty much opinion based.

[dj](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dj) may be a useful tag - let's see what others think first. I'm not sure whether it is needed or is just a subset of [electronic-music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-music)

Comment: Hmm interesting idea for electronic music